# What is the name for the documents that are like "Style Tiles" but more to do with larger objects/elements like contact forms etc

Tags: website-design, typography, style, style-guide

I did a study on design in the browser about a year ago and I remember learning about another tool which designers can use to compliment style tiles. I seem to remember it being called an "object palette"; but now I doubt that was the exact name of it because the object palette is just a part of some adobe app, (can't remember which one - or maybe it's all of them .

Can anyone help me to remember? If style tiles were a device for developing the typography, colours, textures and general mood, then these other things were similar except that they are for larger elements such as contact forms, headers, menus, media players, galleries etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure about this but I came across the term "Pattern Library" and I think that might be the thing I'm thinking about.

Example here: http://patterns.alistapart.com/